# C++ Error when adding objects to vector

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm new with vectors. I'm trying to add objects to a vector. But the program can't compile because I have a problem in the code. But I don't know what is it. The error is:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Line (void)' to 'Line &&'
```

The code is:

```
Line help_line ();
cin >> ln_quan;
vector <Line> figure_line;
for (int i = 0 ; i < ln_quan ; i++)
{
    figure_line.push_back(help_line);
}
```

The compiler says that the error is at the 6-th line (figure_line.push_back(help_line);).

I gave up trying to find a tutorial explaining how to add objects (I give up easily when doing such things...).

And what does 'Line (void)' and 'Line &&' mean? Is 'Line (void)' the class 'Line'? If so, what does '(void)' mean in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Line help_line ();
```

This **does not** mean "`help_line` shall be an instance of `Line` created with the default constructor". It means "`help_line` shall be a function, implemented somewhere else, that takes no arguments and returns a `Line` instance".

The thing you want is spelled `Line help_line;`, with no parentheses.

So, you get the following error message:

```
'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Line (void)' to 'Line &&'
```

`Line &&` is the kind of parameter that `push_back` is expecting. The `&&` doesn't really matter here; it's best thought of, for beginners, as a kind of calling convention. You're still just passing a `Line`, because that's the kind of thing you collect in a vector of `Line`s.

`Line(void)` is "the type of functions that take no arguments and return a `Line` instance". `(void)` is another way to write `()`, for function arguments (it is discouraged in new code, but sometimes needed when interacting with very old C code).

Answer (score 6):

```
Line help_line ();
```

This declares a function, not a `Line`. Use `Line help_line;` instead.

See: [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: Except this is a simpler case than what is usually thought of as "most vexing parse".

Comment: @Karl: Aren't all instances where a variable declaration is interpreted as a function declaration known as a "vexing parse"?

Comment: I think @Karl is right -- as I understand it, the most vexing parse would be something like `Line help_line(Line());`, where constructor arguments cause the ambiguity.

Comment: Can we agree on "quite vexing parse"? :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `help_line` as a function taking no parameters and returning a `Line`. Is that what you intended?

If so, then you need to invoke the function, like this:

```
Line help_line();
...
figure_line.push_back(help_line());
```

If not, and you intended to declare `help_line` as an object of type `Line`, you need this:

```
Line help_line;
...
figure_line.push_back(help_line);
```